# Calling Model function in template not working

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get the category of a skill in a template.
From the post I read, I can't directly get information from a foreign key in a template. 
Instead, I add a function on CharacterSkill models to get the Skill category

Models.py

```
class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)

class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    cat1 = '01'
    SKILLSET_CHOICE = ((cat1:'cat1'))
    skillset_choice = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices = SKILLSET_CHOICE,
        default='',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        )

class CharacterSkill(models.Model):
    character = models.ForeignKey(Character, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def skillcategory(self):
        return Skill.objects.get(id = self.skill).skillset_choice
```

Template

```
skillsetchoice {{item.skillcategory}}
```

But I get an error :

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Skill'
```

I tried to inpect value with the shell console where I can get back the category id but when I use it in template, nothing is working

Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with calling it from the template.

`self.skill` is *already* an instance of Skill. There is no need to query that model explicitly.

```
def skillcategory(self):
    return self.skill.skillset_choice
```

And in fact this method is pretty pointless; you certainly can do it directly in the template:

```
skillsetchoice {{ item.skill.skillset_choice }}
```

Comment: I knew I was complicating my life , it's working your way, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Replace `self.skill` with `self.skill.id` (in older versions of Django your code would work by the way):

```
def skillcategory(self):
    return Skill.objects.get(id = self.skill.id).skillset_choice
```

But this is much better:

```
def skillcategory(self):
    return self.skill.skillset_choice
```

But do you really need this method? You can use:

```
{{ item.skill.skillset_choice }}
```

If you want to display `cat1`, then ([`get_foo_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)):

```
{{ item.skill.get_skillset_choice_display }}
```